# Convert to current swift syntax failed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I keep getting the following error when trying to convert my project to `Swift3`:

> Convert to current swift syntax failed
>       Could not determine bundle identifier for AppNameTests's TEST_HOST: 
>       "/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-bvwsmxtnxztczgaeqridenjdhfmt/Build
>       /Products/Debug (Staging)-iphonesimulator/AppName-dev.app"

Its very frustrating because before I had successfully managed to convert my project but I did some things wrong so decided to reset my git project to the latest commit. Trying to convert it again now fails, even though there should be no difference in the code.

Comment: Look here - [Convert to current swift syntax failed Could not determine bundle identifier fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847807/xcode-8-beta-convert-to-current-swift-syntax-failed-could-not-find-test-host/39594710#39594710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I literally just reset my git again and closed my project and reopened it and then it worked... Silly Xcode