# ApacheThrift on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, thrift

I would like to use Apache Thrift in my project. I tried to follow: https://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageObjectiveC but I faced surprisingly big amount of problems.

What I did is:

1. Downloaded the latest Thrift: 0.10.0
2. Created brand new Xcode project (I'm using Xcode 9.0.1)
3. I generated obj-c classes from example Thrift:

`//idl.thrift`

```
struct Message {
  1: string text,
  2: string date
}

service BulletinBoard {
  void add(1: Message msg),
  list<Message> get()
}
```

4. I added Thrift src to project

Everything should works at this point but unfortunately I get swift compiler error. It looks like the latest Thrift does not support new swift. I tried to convert Thrift sources to the latest Swift, but without success. I keep getting following error:

[image]

I tried to fix it like it is presented here: [Xcode 8 Beta - Convert to Current Swift Syntax Failed: Could not find test host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847807/xcode-8-beta-convert-to-current-swift-syntax-failed-could-not-find-test-host) but also without luck.

Have you any idea why conversion fails?